# Batch script that will monitor a specific folder and its contents for changes and updates

Tags: windows, batch-file, logging

lets say i have a folder and its contents but some one logged in the computer and updated the folder's contents. Now i want is to make an automated log file which will monitor that who and when did the changes on that specific folder and its contents.

Comment: Not really in "old plain batch" but in powershell - https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b

Comment: thanks a lot it helped me a lot at least pushed me to the right direction.

Comment: @user4419802 kindly if you can tell me how to print the user who did it with all the information it will be a lot helpful. thanks in advance

Comment: It seems you want too much from open interfaces. Maybe it would make sense to look at some 3rd party low-level utility like 'Procmon' - https://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx. Here is on automating it with Powershell - http://nomanualrequired.blogspot.ru/2013/04/automating-process-monitor.html

Comment: Well its not what i kind of want. this is a more extensive tool for like forensic. All i want is to just monitor the folder the above script was okay but it only lack that directory making , editing or deleting and the file rename was not logging.